# CakePHP - Include class from a directory outside the app directory

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to include a miscellaneous library class from outside my app (it gets used by different apps).

My app is located at:

```
/var/www/websites/my_website/app/
```

And the class is located at:

```
/var/www/websites/libs/CakePHP/MyClass.php
```

In my bootstrap I'm struggling to figure out how to add the path for loading the classes from that directory:

```
App::build(array('Lib' => array('/var/www/websites/lib/')));

App::uses('MyClass', 'CakePHP');

$myClass = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading shouldn't be done in your bootstrap, but in your `AppController`'s `beforeFilter` method instead.

Also, there is a reserved place for non-Cake libraries, being the `app/Vendor` directory. You can place all your classes in there and then load team easily with:

```
App::uses('MyClass', 'Vendor');
```

If it really needs to be in an alternative path, you need to specify and call the full path instead. And make sure to use the same names. Right now, you're specifying `Lib`, yet calling `CakePHP` as if that was a `build` by itself (which it's not). This won't work. It should look like this instead:

```
App::build(array('Lib' => array('/var/www/websites/lib')));
App::uses('MyClass', 'Lib/CakePHP'); // Define the subdirectory here
```

Also check [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files) on loading vendor files, it has quite some examples.

Comment: I know how to use Vendor files, I already use them.  These files have to be outside the app.

Comment: @BadHorsie OK, well in that case use the `App::uses('MyClass', 'Lib/CakePHP');` syntax instead.

Comment: That only seems to work if I put the build path in the controller like you said, but the class is being included in a model so it makes no sense to have the build path in every controller where I *might* use the model that uses the lib class.  Why can't I put the build path in the model? I get **Fatal error: Class 'AppExceptionRenderer' not found in /var/www/websites/my_website/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php on line 126** Seems like it would be tidier and less hassle to just use a regular `require()`

Comment: Because your Model has nothing to do with loading external classes, this is controller logic. If you just have one Model where you need the class, just load it in it's corresponding controller.